# How to insert square bracket in multi-row table?

Tags: multirow, brackets

I have tried to insert square bracket in multi-row table. As shown in picture, from  Fourth row and second column to seventh row and Third column, I want to insert square pair brackets and "/times2" right side in every cell.

Here is my start code,

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\scalebox{0.7}{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
\hline
Type & VoVNet-39 & VoVNet-29 & Output\\ \hline
Stem & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}3x3 conv, 64,  stride=2\\ 3x3 conv, 64,  stride=1\\ 3x3 conv, 128, stride=1\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}3x3 conv, 32, stride=2\\ 3x3 conv, 32, stride=1\\ 3x3 conv, 64, stride=1\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}112\\ 112\\ 112\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Pooling  & 3x3 max pool, stride=2 & 3x3 max pool, stride=2  & 56x56  \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DRF block\\ stage 2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{[}3x3 conv, 128{]}x5  \\ concat \& {[}1x1 conv, 256{]}\end{tabular}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{[}3x3 conv, 64{]}x5\\ concat \& {[}1x1 conv, 64{]}\end{tabular} & 56x56 \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DRF block\\ stage 3\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{[}3x3 conv, 160{]}x5\\ concat \& {[}1x1 conv, 512{]}\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{[}3x3 conv, 80{]}x5\\ concat \& {[}1x1 conv, 128{]}\end{tabular} & 28x28  \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DRF block\\ stage 4\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{[}3x3 conv, 192{]}x5\\ concat \& {[}1x1 conv, 786{]}\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{[}3x3 conv, 192{]}x5\\ concat \& {[}1x1 conv, 786{]}\end{tabular} & 14x14  \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DRF block\\ stage 5\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{[}3x3 conv, 192{]}x5\\ concat \& {[}1x1 conv, 786{]}\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{[}3x3 conv, 192{]}x5\\ concat \& {[}1x1 conv, 786{]}\end{tabular} & 7x7  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\vspace{-0.35cm}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest removing the vertical rules that add nothing to the understanding of the table (they actually hinder reading).

For the split cells it's better to define a specific command that can be supplemented with another for bracketing them.

Instead of `x` I used `\texttimes`.

Don't scale your tables; here `\small` is sufficient for the standard text width of `article`: experiment with your own setup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp,array,booktabs}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\bsplitcell}[1]{$\left[\splitcell{#1}\right]$}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lccc@{}}
\toprule
Type & VoVNet-39 & VoVNet-29 & Output\\
\midrule
Stem &
  \splitcell{3\texttimes3 conv, 64,  stride=2\\ 3\texttimes3 conv, 64,  stride=1\\
             3\texttimes3 conv, 128, stride=1} &
  \splitcell{3\texttimes3 conv, 32, stride=2\\ 3\texttimes3 conv, 32, stride=1\\
             3\texttimes3 conv, 64, stride=1} &
  \splitcell{112\\ 112\\ 112} \\
\midrule
Pooling  & 3\texttimes3 maxpool, stride=2 & 3\texttimes3 maxpool, stride=2  & 56\texttimes56  \\
\midrule
\splitcell{DRF block\\ stage 2} &
  \bsplitcell{3\texttimes3 conv, 128\texttimes5  \\ concat \& 1\texttimes1 conv, 256}\texttimes2 &
  \bsplitcell{3\texttimes3 conv, 64\texttimes5 \\ concat \& 1\texttimes1 conv, 64}\texttimes2 &
  56\texttimes56 \\
\midrule
\splitcell{DRF block\\ stage 3} &
  \bsplitcell{3\texttimes3 conv, 160\texttimes5 \\ concat \& 1\texttimes1 conv, 512}\texttimes2 &
  \bsplitcell{3\texttimes3 conv, 80\texttimes5 \\ concat \& 1\texttimes1 conv, 128}\texttimes2 &
  28\texttimes28 \\
\midrule
\splitcell{DRF block\\ stage 4} &
  \bsplitcell{3\texttimes3 conv, 192\texttimes5 \\ concat \& 1\texttimes1 conv, 786}\texttimes2 &
  \bsplitcell{3\texttimes3 conv, 192\texttimes5\\ concat \& 1\texttimes1 conv, 786}\texttimes2 &
  14\texttimes14 \\
\midrule
\splitcell{DRF block\\ stage 5} &
  \bsplitcell{3\texttimes3 conv, 192\texttimes5\\ concat \& 1\texttimes1 conv, 786}\texttimes2 &
  \bsplitcell{3\texttimes3 conv, 192\texttimes5\\ concat \& 1\texttimes1 conv, 786}\texttimes2 &
  7\texttimes7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To distinguish the categories such as VoVNet-39/VoVNet-29, I think vertical line is needed. Could you suggest with vertical lines?

Comment: @youngwanlee The space is more than enough, in my opinion. If you feel the space is too small, use `\footnotesize`.

Comment: @egreg I suggest using something like `\newcommand{\tx}{\texttimes}` to simplify your code. You must waste much time in typing these commands.

Comment: @egreg I really appreciate your reply. Could you let me know how to reduce space between columns in your suggested table?

Comment: @egreg Actually, this table should be located in left-top side in a two-column paper. When I copy and paste the table, the font size in the table is small and the space between columns is too large. So I remove \small and insert \scalebox{0.47}  to adjust the table size. But the font size is still small.

Comment: @youngwanlee Use `table*` to get a float that straddles both columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `makecell` package:

```
%\bgroup
%\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
    \hline
    Type & VoVNet-39 & VoVNet-29 & Output \\
    \hline
    Stem &
    \makecell{
        3x3 conv, 64,  stride=2\\
        3x3 conv, 64,  stride=1\\ 
        3x3 conv, 128, stride=1
    }
    & 
    \makecell{
        3x3 conv, 32,  stride=2\\
        3x3 conv, 32,  stride=1\\ 
        3x3 conv, 64, stride=1
    }
    &
    \makecell{112\\112\\112}\\
    \hline
    Pooling & 3x3 max pool, stride=2 & 3x3 max pool, stride=2 & 56x56 \\
    \hline
    \makecell{
        DRF block\\
        stage 1
    } 
    &
    $\Big[$
    \makecell{
        [3x3 conv, 128]x5\\
        concat \& [1x1 conv, 256]
    }
    $\Big]\times2$
    &
    $\Big[$
    \makecell{
        [3x3 conv, 64]x5\\
        concat \& [1x1 conv, 64]
    }
    $\Big]\times2$
    & 56x56\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
%\egroup
```

[image]

I recommend the table should be simpler, or you should provide us a **minimal working example** (MWE). In that case, the code above will be much simpler.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: thanks for reply. Could you let me know how to enlarge the square bracket?